# How to keep various-topic R script at hand?

Tags: r

I have written and collected R code on various topics that solve particular problems at hand. I stored the R script/code in .txt files. I have now 100s of them.

How do you keep your R code at hand efficiently?

Comment: I clip code-snippets with `evernote` off the website and `tag` them.

Comment: I use mind maps (http://freemind.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 9):

@Manetheran has the right idea: write a package.  It's [easy to do](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/#package-development) (especially with RStudio).  Read "[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)" and then on top of that learn about roxygen2 (which allows you to document each function in-line and avoid writing .Rd files).

Then you can use `devtools` to load your package locally, or once it's stable if you think other people can use the functions you can submit your package to CRAN.

Comment: I think it's overkill to write a package to bundle various code snippets for various purposes, that are much like in the form of copy-paste cheat sheet. Not only it might be impossible to turn them into clear layers or functions with a clear interface; but most importantly, it won't help *you* in keeping them efficiently at hand.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, your comment is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to **keep it simple**. I use Total Commander and when I need an example which uses some R function, I just do <kbd>Alt-F7</kbd> and search for `*.R` files which contain the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

I use RStudio and have created two or three basic scripts.  I save my much-used functions in the basic script that is most appropriate.  Then, at the start of an RStudio script for a project, I source one or more of the basic scripts as is appropriate.